# Find average of last 14 values in pandas column excluding values that are 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where there is a column of values:

```
    col1
0   1
1   3
2   6
3   2
4   4
5   0
6   0
7   3
8   4
9   5
10  7
11  5
12  2
13  5
14  4
15  0
16  0
17  2
18  4
19  5
```

I want to create a new column in the database which calculates an average of the last 14 values in the column, for every row. However, this is to be carried out on the condition that the sum of the last 14 values is divided by the number of values which are greater than 0.

For example, for row 19, the average would be the sum of the last 14 values (including that of row 19) divided by 11, as there are 3 zeros in the last 14 values.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for `rolling().sum()`:

```
N = 14

df['col1'].rolling(N).sum()/df['col1'].ne(0).rolling(N).sum()
```

Output:

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
7          NaN
8          NaN
9          NaN
10         NaN
11         NaN
12         NaN
13    3.916667
14    4.166667
15    4.272727
16    4.100000
17    4.100000
18    4.100000
19    4.181818
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```